# How to write POST function for nested-serializers Django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am unable to write a .create method for this nested serailizer. I want to create an appointment row for every new appointment and for appointment_detail table i want to create as many rows as many services are opted.

my **models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='services')
service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.service_name + ' in ' + str(self.category)

class Appointment_Status(models.Model):
status = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def __str__(self):
    return self.status

class Appointment(models.Model):
"""This is the model where all the orders/Appointments will be saved"""
user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
zorg        = models.ForeignKey(Zorg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
branch      = models.ForeignKey(Zorg_Branche, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='branch')
timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
status      = models.ForeignKey(Appointment_Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
totaltime   = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)


def __str__(self):
    return  str(self.user) + ' -> '  + str(self.zorg)

class AppointmentDetail(models.Model):
appointment  = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='appointment')
related_name='category')
service      = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='service')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.appointment) + '  ' + str(self.service)
```

in **serializers.py**

```
class UserAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
                'id',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email_id',
                'mobile_number',
                'birthdate',
                'photo_url',
                'gender',
              ]

class ZorgBranchAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Zorg_Branche
    exclude = ['id', 'zorg']

class CategoryAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
This serailizer is to serialize and deserailize category model
"""
class Meta:
    model = Categories
    fields = ['category_name']

class ServiceAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
This is a serializer to serializer and deserailize service serailizer.
"""
category = CategoryAppointmentSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = Service
    exclude = ['id']

class ZorgAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Zorg
    fields = [
                'id',
                 'name',
                 'salon_email_id',
                 'website'
             ]

class AppointmentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


service = ServiceAppointmentSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = AppointmentDetail
    exclude = ['id', 'appointment', ]

class AppointmentStatusSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Appointment_Status
    fields = ['status']

class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
appointment = AppointmentDetailSerializer(many=True)
status = AppointmentStatusSerilizer()
user = UserAppointmentSerializer()
zorg = ZorgAppointmentSerializer()
branch = ZorgBranchAppointmentSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = Appointment
    fields = [
            'id', 
            'status',
            'appointment',
            'user',
            'zorg',
            'branch',
            'timestamp',
            'totaltime',
            'total_price'
        ]

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.pop('user')
    zorg = validated_data.pop('zorg')
    status = validated_data.pop('status')
    branch = validated_data.pop('branch')
    appointment = validated_data.pop('appointment')

    for app in appointment:
        service = app.pop('service')
        category = service.pop('category')
        category_instance = Categories.objects.get(**category)
        service_instance = Service.objects.get(category = category_instance, **service)
        appointment_detail = AppointmentDetail.objects.create(service=service_instance)

    user_instance = User.objects.get(**user)
    zorg_instance = Zorg.objects.get(**zorg)
    status_instance = Appointment_Status.objects.get(**status)
    branch_instance = Zorg_Branche.objects.get(**branch)
   
    writable_data = Appointment.objects.create( user = user_instance, zorg = zorg_instance, status = 
    status_instance, branch = branch_instance, **validated_data)


    return writable_data
```

I am able to make everything else work except the appointment. I am unable to pass the appointment portion to the writable data from the for loop. Here's the JSON I want to use.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "status": {
        "status": "Pending"
    },
    "appointment": [
        {
            "service": {
                "category": {
                    "category_name": "Spa"
                },
                "service_name": "normal spa",
                "time": 0,
                "price": "700.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "service": {
                "category": {
                    "category_name": "Facial"
                },
                "service_name": "Normal Facial",
                "time": 0,
                "price": "1500.00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "id": 23,
        "first_name": "Sample",
        "last_name": "Sample",
        "email_id": "sample@gmail.com",
        "mobile_number": "9999999999",
        "birthdate": "2001-01-22",
        "photo_url": "",
        "gender": 1
    },
    "zorg": {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Sample",
        "salon_email_id": "sample@gmail.com",
        "website": "http://sample.in"
    },
    "branch": {
        "address": "Sample Plaza",
        "city": "Sample",
        "state": "Sample Pradesh",
        "country": "India",
        "zip_code": "462003"
    },
    "timestamp": "2020-09-25T20:13:28.806558Z",
    "totaltime": 0,
    "total_price": "0.00"
}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest, change the approach because performance specific its really wired. You should handle Appointment detail in views.py just by overriding perform_create method if you where using generic views and handle all your validation in your serializer. You should use bulk create post all the validation, instead of single db operation of create.

Comment: @AshishGupta what kind of performance issues are we looking here? Also I am not very experienced with drf, can you recommend me some resources?

Comment: If you look into AppointmentSerializer with create method, the method has for loop and hitting to the db for each detail. Instead of that make use of bulk create method (https://medium.com/swlh/efficient-bulk-create-with-django-rest-framework-f73da6af7ddc). Ideally looping and querying to db is always costly operations. We should always avoid such problem and make our code more efficient.